# complex table with multirow doesn't close all the boxes

Tags: multirow

I have made a big table with a table editor and there are two lines that doesn't finish in the place they are suposed to finish.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{layout}
\newcommand{\rot}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h]   \footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{5-20}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            &                                             & \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\textbf{ACCIONS}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{5-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            &                                             & \multicolumn{10}{|c}{FASE DE CONSTRUCCIÓ}                                                                                                                                                                                                               & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{FASE D'EXTRACCIÓ}                                                                                                                 \\ \cline{5-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            &                                             & \rot{preparació de l'àrea} &\rot{ construcció diposits externs}  &\rot{ infr. transport} &\rot{ maquinaria transport} &\rot{ perforació del pou} &\rot{ revestiment de carcasses} &\rot{ injecció de ciment} &\rot{ perforació pou horitzontal} &\rot{ recollida i transport de residus} &\rot{ consum de recursos} &\rot{ Maquinaria de transport} &\rot{ Bombeig solució} &\rot{ extracció solució resultant} &\rot{ recollida i transport de residus} &\rot{ consum de recuros} &\rot{ transport de personal} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{13}{*}{\textbf{MEDI FÍSIC}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{10}{*}{ ABIÓTIC}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{Atmosfera}} & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Contaminació gasos}    &                      &                     &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{4-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Contaminació pols}     &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{4-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{contaminació acústica} &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{3-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{4}{*}{Sòl}}       & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Contaminació}          &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{4-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                           & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Erosió}                &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{4-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                           & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Ús del sòl}            &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{4-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\textbf{}}                             & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                               & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}                           & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Sismicitat}            &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{3-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\textbf{}}                             & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                               & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Aigua}}     & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Aigues superficials}   &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{4-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Aigues subterraneas}   &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{4-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                            & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Recurs hídric}         &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{2-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\textbf{}}                             & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{BIÓTIC}}        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Vegetació}                                                               &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{3-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\textbf{}}                             & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                               & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Fauna}                                                                   &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{3-20} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{}}                             & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                               & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Paisatge}                                                                &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{MEDI SOCIOECONÒMIC}}}                                                & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Demografia}                                                              &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{3-20} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{}                                                                                            & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Turisme}                                                                 &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{3-20} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{}                                                                                            & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Economia}                                                                &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \cline{3-20} 
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{}                                                                                            & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Salud }                                                                  &                      &                               &                 &                      &                    &                          &                    &                            &                                  &                    &                         &                 &                             &                                  &                   &                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you mean the lines at left of "atmosfera" and "aigua", right?

Comment: never do `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}` except in the first column. Always do `\multicolumn{1}{l|}` The rules are at the _right_ edge of each cell.

Comment: do not use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` for the lines where you use "atmosfera" and "aigua" (with `\multirow`). They will delete the vertical lines.